# Ambiguous Flash Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I was browsing through the tags to look for some to edit, in the pursuit of the research assistant badge when I cam across the "flash" tag.

It currently has 8 questions associated with it, but they both use "flash" in a very different meaning:

- 3 questions about "flashing an SD card"
- 3 questions about "flash drives"
- 1 question about "Adobe Flash"
- 1 question about a "flash sensor"

These obviously don't belong together. Should we disambiguate the "flash" tag by making the 4 alternatives listed above?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this was another pointless grab bag tag that's never had a description to specify whether it means flash player, flashing an EEPROM, etc., so it is now dead (and a synonym for [video](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video) to prevent it coming  back).

Thanks again.